# Unexpected token syntax error using Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, extjs

Ok I am using the Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy to pull json data from a remote server (which I happen to manage) and am receiving this error:  **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

I am querying a database with the following PHP page and encoding the results in json:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
$db_name = "foo"; // The name of the database being used.

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "foo user", "foo pass") or die ("Unable to connect to    database.");
 mysql_select_db("$db_name", $db);

echo '{"recipes": ';     
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_recipes"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);

$_ResultSet = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $_ResultSet[] = $row;
}
   echo json_encode($_ResultSet); 
   echo "}";  
?>
```

And here is the code I am using to make the Cross domain call using Sencha:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
model  : 'Recipes',
            sorters: [

                    {property: 'recipeName', direction: 'ASC'}
                     ],
            getGroupString : function(record) {
            return record.get('recipeName')[0];
            },
        proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
            url: 'http://myvisalusdiet.com/app/json_output2.php'
        }),
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'recipes',
            idProperty : 'recipeName',
            id: 'id'
        }),
        autoLoad : true
    });
```

Anybody see anything unusual which would case the syntax error?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I am having a hard time [validating](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) your json. Currently its wrapped in (parenthesis) rather than {brackets}

```
([{"id":"3","ingredients2":"4 oz. (1\/2 cup orange juice)","ingredients3"
...
,"ingredients":"6 oz. skim milk","website":null}]);
```

and not sure that javascript is too helpful, firebug for example would like to see "application/json" != "application/javascript" for laying out data. this doesnt impact parsing/linting though.